# How to get the image url base on the button id used in wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

My goal is to get the image url according to the button I click and pass the url value on the proper input text/box. Also I used the media library of wordpress to get an image.

---

I have this html codes:

```
<label for="upload_image">
  First Slide <br />
   <input id="imageurl-1" type="text" size="36" name="ad_image" value="http://" />
   <input id="1" class="button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
   <br />Enter a URL or upload an image
</label>

<label for="upload_image">
  Second Slide <br />
   <input id="imageurl-2" type="text" size="36" name="ad_image" value="http://" />
   <input id="2" class="button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
   <br />Enter a URL or upload an image
</label>
```

And this is my script based on the tutorial [here](http://www.webmaster-source.com/2013/02/06/using-the-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-your-plugin-or-theme/). I just enhance a little to allow me to select multiple images.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var custom_uploader;

 $('.button').each( function(index) {
    $(this).click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var button_id = this.id;
        alert(button_id); //only to know the button id i clicked
        //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
        if (custom_uploader) {
            custom_uploader.open();
            return;
        }

        //Extend the wp.media object
        custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: 'Choose Image',
            button: {
                text: 'Choose Image'
            },
            multiple: false
        });

        //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
        custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
            attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
                $('#imageurl-' + button_id).val(attachment.url);
        });

        //Open the uploader dialog
        custom_uploader.open();

    });
 });

});
```

The situation is. When I click the button 1 and chose an image, the image url would fill my input text(id is "imageurl-1") and this is correct. The problem is on the button 2, because after I selected an image, the image url from that button 2 would replace the value on the first input text(id is "imageurl-1") which is should filled on the input text 2(id is "imageurl-2"). I guess I'm having difficult on this part of code

> $('#imageurl-' + button_id).val(attachment.url);

which the button_id must be also "refreshed I think" every time I click the button in order to make it perfect. Hope anyone could help me.

Comment: What did you do finally? Could you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I think callback to the select event on line
    `custom_uploader.on('select', function() {`
is bound to the scope where button_id has value of 1.
There is also no sense to iterate over all .button elements,
`$('.button').click(function(e) {` will be good enough.

Easy solution maybe to remove previous callbacks with `custom_uploader.off('select')` before line with
 `custom_uploader.on('select', function() {`, so it will get new callback on each click event.

Comment: It seems it doesn't work. Because the second time when the `if (custom_uploader)` returns true, and opens the custom_uploader by `custom_uploader.open()`, the codes below that won't be executed. So `on` and/or`off` doesn't trigger.